# how to plot the dates retrieved from database on the LineChart in Android

Tags: android, database, datetime, achartengine

I'm developing a simple android application that stores current(now) date into sqlite database.
Later it retrieve the date values from the database to an activity and plot them on the line chart with some values assigned to dates.
I have done all the coding like retrieving the saved dates from database and storing them to a ArrayList, coding for the line chart and everything. Finally I'm getting a nullpointer exception. kindly take a look at my code and provide a solution. It would be a simple task to find the exception in the program.

Here is the layout xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Date" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chartButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chart" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

chartButton is for showing the graph using the intent.

Here is the part of the code for line chart:

```
public void openChart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Date[] dt = new Date[c.getCount()];
        //int i=0;
        c=dbAdapter.getAllRecords();
        c.moveToFirst();
        List<Date> dt = new ArrayList<Date>();

        while(c.moveToNext()){
            String stringDate = c.getString(1);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(stringDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dt.add(date);//dt[i] = date;
            //i++;
        }

        Double[] numbers = null; //= {20.0,20.1,20.2,20.3,20.4,20.5,20.6,20.7,20.8,20.9,21.0,21.2};

        TimeSeries numbersTime = new TimeSeries("Numbers Time");

        for(int i2=0;i2<dt.size();i2++){
            numbers[i2]=(double) i2;
            numbersTime.add(dt.get(i2),numbers[i2]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(numbersTime);


        XYSeriesRenderer numbersRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        numbersRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        numbersRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        numbersRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        numbersRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        numbersRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

         multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits vs Views Chart");
         multiRenderer.setXTitle("Date Time");
         multiRenderer.setYTitle("Double Numbers");
         multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

         multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(numbersRenderer);

         // Creating an intent to plot line chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
            Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);


            // Start Activity
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Here is the Cursor method in the DBAdapter class:

```
Cursor getAllRecords(){
        String[] columns = {COL_ID,COL_DATE};
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null); 
    }
```

Here is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dateexample.seenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dateexample.seenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the LogCat report:

```
01-25 18:11:39.656: D/AndroidRuntime(28121): Shutting down VM
01-25 18:11:39.656: W/dalvikvm(28121): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.example.dateexample.seenu.MainActivity.openChart(MainActivity.java:103)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.example.dateexample.seenu.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.example.dateexample.seenu.MainActivity.openChart(MainActivity.java:103)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.example.dateexample.seenu.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-25 18:11:39.992: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And finally I'm getting null pointerException showing in the logCat.
Once again I request kindly provide some solution for me.

Comment: Post the LogCat with the Exception..

Comment: posted logCat report...Check it once

Comment: could you please indicate line 103 in MainActivity's openChart() function?

Comment: It is  'numbers[i2]=(double) i2; ' that is in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a unitialized array (`Double[] numbers = null;`) that you are attempting to add values to. you need to allocate `numbers` array prior to adding values to it.

`Double[] numbers = new Double[100];`

note: you might want to look into more flexible storage containers (Vectors, ArrayList, etc) that grow as you add to them.

Comment: Thanks for answering... plz provide a sample code that need to be implemented to correct error. It could be helpful.

Comment: hello I have corrected however, now I'm getting ArrayoutofBounds Exception at line 104(just after the previous one --line:103)

Comment: well, i assume it's the same array. you'll have to increase the initial allocated number (in my example, 100) until you have room. that's why i suggested looking into ArrayList or Vector or ??

Comment: `Double numbers = new Double[dt.size()];` should do it.

Comment: Ya, I got it, but how can I retrieve date from a sqlite database and assign it a 'Date' instance?

Comment: let's close out this question as your initial question has been answered. Feel free to your Date field in another question. glad i could help!

Comment: Hi David here is my other question take a look at it.                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523151/how-to-retrieve-the-dates-from-database-and-plot-them-on-the-line-chart-in-andro